# How to use AdaptiveCards v1.1 in BotBuilder Node.js SDK 4

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I would like to use the newest [version 1.1 of AdaptiveCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/wiki/1.1-Feature-List) in the BotBulder Node.js SDK 4 to use the new features such as vertical alignment. However, the [CardFactory.adaptiveCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/cardfactory?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#adaptivecard) only allows version 1.0.

- Is it possible to use the AdaptiveCards SDK itself to render AdaptiveCards for use in chat? I am using AdaptiveCards in Telegram, hence they need to be rendered into an image. I tried using the AdaptiveCards [method .render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/render-a-card) but failed due to the issue described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1012).
- If not, is this planned for the future?

Answer (score 1):

The BotFramework SDK does not currently support the most recent release of AdaptiveCards - v1.1; however, someone has just submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/702) to the development team on GitHub to incorporate the updated version into the SDK. Hopefully, the newest release will be developed into the framework and will work with the CardFactory soon.

In the meantime, the user who submitted the feature request also suggested a possible workaround. They recommend creating a DOM object which will allow you to render the JSON card into HTML using the AdaptiveCards Library. Then, you can use Puppeteer - a high-level API to control Chrome - to render the HTML and convert it into an image. The image can then be sent to the user in the chat in place of a card. Unfortunately, you do lose a lot of the card's functionality such as actions, but you will be able to use some of the new formatting features in the new release of AdaptiveCards. I would recommend looking at [this post](https://runkit.com/rcasto/adaptive-card-nodejs) and the [Puppeteer Repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) if you think this solution may work for you.